# Перебрать два списка разной величины в одном цикле

Tags: python, циклы, list, for

Вот мой код:

```py
a = [45678, 34567, 23456]
b = [24566, 43224, 44563, 23565, 45452, 23564, 32553]

for a_, b_ in zip(a, b):
    print(a_)
    print(b_)
```

Мне нужно перебрать эти оба списка в одном цикле, `zip` перебирает только столько элементов, сколько их в списке `a`.
Есть еще `zip_longest`, но у него тоже есть одно "но", то что вместо пустых символов выводится `None`.

Как сделать так, чтобы вывелся полностью весь первый список и полностью весь второй список посредством одного цикла `for`? Либо это можно сделать каким-то другим способом?

Результат должен быть следующий:

```
45678
34567
23456 

24566
43224
44563
23565
45452
23564
32553
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе резульат, который вы хотите получить. Непонятно чем вам не подходит `zip_longest`...

Comment: У вас сначала выводится один список, а потом другой. Это не совпадает с вашим кодом и описанием.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужна функция zip_longest из модуля itertools. Следуя документации [этой функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), Вам надо указать дополнительный аргумент `fillvalue`. Если вы хотите чтобы вместо None была пустая строка, тогда ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [45678, 34567, 23456]
b = [24566, 43224, 44563, 23565, 45452, 23564, 32553]

for a_, b_ in zip_longest(a,b, fillvalue=" "):
    print(a_)
    print(b_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по результату, который вы хотите получить, проще всего будет работать со строками:

```
In [45]: print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in a]))
45678
34567
23456

In [46]: print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in b]))
24566
43224
44563
23565
45452
23564
32553
```

PS использование единого цикла для получения данного вывода на экран считаю нецелесообразным.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю так:

```
a = [45678, 34567, 23456]
b = [24566, 43224, 44563, 23565, 45452, 23564, 32553]

a.extend(b)

for i in (a):
    print(i)
```